# How to find a LinkLabel or Button on TabPage

Tags: c#, button, controls, tabpage, linklabel

I'm trying to put dynamicaly a LinkLabel (also I traied to put a button) in a TabPage:

```
LinkLabel newLinkLabelButton = new LinkLabel();
newLinkLabelButton.Text = "Login";
newLinkLabelButton.Name = "linkLabel_11";
tabs.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(newLinkLabelButton);
```

Now I'm trying to find this control on the specificf TabPage with function

```
newLoginLinkLabel = (LinkLabel)Helper.GetLinkLabelByTagAndfamily(tabs.TabPages[0], _name);
```

where the function body is:

```
public static Control GetControlByTagAndfamily(TabPage _tab, string _name)
{
  Control rez = new Control();
  foreach (Control ctrl in _tab.Controls)
  {
      if (ctrl.Name == _name)
      {
        rez = ctrl;
        break;
      }
   }
   return rez;
}
```

But the function never founds a LinkLabel or a Button inside **_tab.Controls** collection. I observed the collection contains founds Labels only, if I trying to find some labels inside.

Pleas help to solve this.

Comment: At what point of the page life cycle are you adding the dynamic controls? And at what point are you trying to find them?

Comment: By the way, `if (ctrl.Name == _name) return ctrl;` would suffice, no need for `break`;

Comment: @Andrei I add LinkLabel at on Form1_Load. Then, I'm tryind to find-it on some button Click event.

Comment: You could rewrite the body of the helper-method to a much shorter solution: `return _tabl.Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == _name)` for finding a LinkLabel or `return _tabl.Controls.Cast<Control>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == _name)` for any control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem is solved, the code above is correct. The problem was in wrong **_name** calculation before using it in

```
GetControlByTagAndfamily(TabPage _tab, string _name);
```